# I got NG0203 error while using Angular inject() method in custom property decorator

Tags: angular, typescript

I got this error in my angular application:

> Uncaught Error: NG0203:
> inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `EnvironmentInjector#runInContext`

I have a custom decorator:

```js
import {Type, InjectionToken, inject} from '@angular/core';

export function SgInject<T>(token: Type<T> | InjectionToken<T> | any) {
  return function (target: any, key: string) {
    target[key] = inject(token);
  };
}
```

and I'm using it like this:

```js
@Directive()
export class ComponentBase {
  @SgInject(NgZone)
  ngZone: NgZone;
}
```

I'm using the property decorator in constructor context, why I still get this error?

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `Inject` instead of `inject` like the following:

```js
import {Type, InjectionToken, Inject} from '@angular/core';

export function SgInject<T>(token: Type<T> | InjectionToken<T> | any) {
  return function (target: any, key: string) {
    target[key] = Inject(token);
  };
}
```

Comment: `Inject` is a `ParamDecorator` and is used in constructor with `@`!
example: 
class MyComponent {
  constructor(@Inject(TOKEN) token) {}
}